# VST plugins not displaying properly

Tags: 11.10, music, plugins, interface

I tried to work with several Linux native VST instruments plugins but, each time, I had the same problem: the interface does not display properly.
An example of what I mean:

[image]

No text, as you can see.
I tried the following: tonescape (http://www.mucoder.net/en/tonespace/) and every TAL plugins (http://sourceforge.net/projects/distrho/files/Ports/TAL-Plugins/).

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 2D.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a proprietary application, and perhaps a problem with it. Have you tried contacting the developers or community forum on that site for support?

Comment: No I haven't. But as I had this problem on several VST, I thought it was an interface problem or something. Thanks for the help anyway!